sf project deploy start to Production Org doesn't work
Since approximately 2 weeks I have been facing the following issue:
When I run sf project deploy start within my VS Code terminal, the code gets "deployed".
Meaning the command executes as expected inside of the terminal without any errors and the deployment is visible and succesfull inside of my org under "Deployment Status"
However, when I test my newly pushed code and inspect the .js, it hasn't been updated at all. Sometimes it works, often it doesn't.
I tried clearing my browser cash already, but this doesn't work.
Has anyone any idea on how to resolve this issue? As development now becomes almost impossible to do

Try unchecking "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" in Setup > Session Settings > Caching

Thank you! This fixed the issue!
